# How does the contain method match?

Tags: java, string, linked-list, string-matching

Is the statement `list.contains("are")` *(have commented it)* being checked by matching character to character ?

```
import java.util.*;

class Tester {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String arr[] = {"how","are","you","veena"};
        LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
        for(String s : arr) {
            list.add(s);
        }
        if(list.contains("are")) { // STATEMENT
            System.out.println("Found !");
        }
    }
}
```

In this program `if` statement works. How does the `contain` method work ?

Answer (score 2):

That method iterates over the linked list, and compare each element with the element passed by invoking `equals()` method. In this case, it will invoke `String#equals(Object)` method.

Answer (score 0):

this is implementations of method `contains` and `indexOf` from `LinkedList`

```
public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return indexOf(o) != -1;
    }

   public int indexOf(Object o) {
        int index = 0;
        if (o == null) {
            for (Node<E> x = first; x != null; x = x.next) {
                if (x.item == null)
                    return index;
                index++;
            }
        } else {
            for (Node<E> x = first; x != null; x = x.next) {
                if (o.equals(x.item))
                    return index;
                index++;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

so as you see it is iterating trough array till it finds first matching element